# Performance difference extracting and copying in Asp.Net website with C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, extract

I have almost 100 website that will update in a condition, I have a winzip archive that contains the files that replaces those websites. I want to know that

1. I can extract that files in a folder and then copy them to all 100 websites folders
2. I can extract the archive directly to 100 websites folders

which one is better in performance and less prone to errors.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that this isn't programming related, but I'm 100% sure it doesn't matter until it actually does.  Pick one and go with it and worry about this when you encounter issues.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly better solution (seeing as your source code is the same in each case):

Have your source code in one place on the system and point all the different web sites to the same physical folder.